# cannot run google app engine hello world application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I installed python 2.7.5 32bit for windows.
I installed GAE python SDK.

I created a folder named 'helloworld', with a file app.yaml like this:
[image]
and another file `main.py` like this:
[image]

Then I start the app like this:
[image]

so far so good.

Then I try to access it using

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

the page cannot load, and there is this error on console:
[image]

could you please help me out guys?

Comment: The traceback doesn't seem to fit the code you show in `main.py`. It goes into CherryPy and I don't see why it should.